# How to add HTML to middle of a Razor C# ternary operation?

Tags: c#, html, razor

I have a paragraph that is going to be sent as an email, and I want to check if a variable isn't null, if it is not null I want to add an html break so it is added on a new line.

Here is the code that doesn't work:

```
@{
string var1 = "var1";
string var2 = "var2";
string var3 = null;
}
<p>
    Var1: @var1
    Var2: @var2
    @(var3 = (var3  != null) ?) <br> @("Var3: " + var3  : ""; @var3.ToString())
</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@if (var3 != null)
{
    <br/>
}
else
{
    // your stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this was an easy fix.

```
@if (var3!= null)
{
    <p> Product: @var3 </p>
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/asp/razor_cs_logic.asp

I was used to PHP where to mix PHP and HTML you had to close the PHP tag add html, then open a new PHP tag.